# What is the meaning of this not-so-literal, tricky expression "schlecht tun können"?

Tags: meaning

> Ich **kann** mir Namen **schlecht** merken.

In the sentence above, the meaning of *schlecht* is as straightforward as they come: "I'm ***bad***/*terrible* at remembering names".

---

In the following instance, however, I suppose I cannot take its meaning literally as *badly*.

> Father: Du gehst nicht mit ihm?
>
> Mother: Ich **kann** ihm **schlecht** die Hand halten, wenn er ernst genommen werden soll.

My assumption: "I ***can't exactly*** hold his hand" or "I ***can't very well*** hold his hand"

---

I wonder if this **"kann ... schlecht"** is close to any of the following:

> "Ich **kann** ihm **kaum** die Hand halten, wenn ..."
>
> or: "Ich **kann** ihm **nicht gerade** die Hand halten, wenn ..."
>
> or: "Ich **kann** ihm **unmöglich** die Hand halten, wenn ..."

Comment: Your assumption is corect. But your additional examples only confuse the issue, because each of them also involves non-literal senses of words, some more similar to your example of non-literal "schlecht", some less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a figurative phrase where someone answers a silly question with a contradicting conclusion. The meaning is a bit sarcastic.

> „Marion ist geflogen?“ — „Sie kann ja schlecht zu Fuß nach New York gehen.“

*“Marion flew?” — “She can't possibly walk to New York by foot, can she?”*

This is **also** the case for your example. The question is silly in the view of the person asked, so she answered it with a contradicting example. Like she was holding the hand (of the son during the job interview.)

Comment: Your constructed example may involve silliness and sarcasm, but in OP's question, that wasn't the case; and it need not be in general, I think.

Comment: The original example is also sarcastic. The question was silly in the view of the person who answered. That's why she chose the contradicting example "I could not hold his hand, could I?"